# Cannot connect to Perforce server via visual client

Tags: windows, perforce

I set up a new Perforce free service on my home server.  I am able to connect to the service on the same machine using the visual client targetting localhost:1666.  When I try to connect from my desktop I am unable to connect. I originally tried my public IP which is forwarded to my server, but when that didn't work I tried targetting my server locally as Server: "192.168.1.105:1666" In either case I get a similar error of:

```
Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
TCP connect to 192.168.1.105:1666 failed.
connect: 192.168.1.105:1666: WSAETIMEDOUT
```

On my server "p4 set" shows:

```
C:\Users\Hephaestus>p4 set
P4EDITOR=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe (set)
P4PASSWD=13C72FC3B6AE5DF224D835D7A26332A0 (set)
P4PORT=1666
P4ROOT=D:\p4
P4USER=Hephaestus (set)
P4_1666_CHARSET=none (set)
```

On my desktop "p4 set" shows:

```
P4EDITOR=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe (set)
P4PORT=50.137.244.199:1666 (set)
P4USER=jelamb (set)
```

I've also worked through most of this: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2960/. I tried turning my server's firewall off completely.

I've spent hours trying to figure this out and I'm just stumped. Why would I be unable to connect?

Comment: That KB article has all the right things to check. This is almost certainly a network configuration problem, but those are hard to diagnose remotely. You can try using tools like "ping" or "telnet" or "ssh" (e.g., Putty) from your desktop to try to figure out where the connection is being refused. Since you mention both a public IP which is being forwarded, and a private IP (192.168.*) behind some sort of NAT router, you've obviously got some network equipment in place that you should be able to connect to and configure to authorize the Perforce connection on port 1666.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out that for whatever reason, adding the config stuff as system variables through Windows didn't do what I needed.  Adding them via p4 command-line commands did the trick.  Weird, but it works now :/.